# Adding additional y-axis on time series data formulated by xts package

Tags: r, xts

I know the similar ones have been discussed once again. But my question is on the wholly new scenario. And I applied these old methods, which does not work for me.

I use Rstudio 0.97551 under Windows XP.

I used `xts` package to draw multiple (usually two) time series into one plot and it works fine. However, it seems that`xts()` and `xtsExtra()` did not support the normal plot functions in R and I cannot use usual commands to add additional y-axis on it.

My time series data is some finance data with irregular time intervals and that's the reason I feel using specific time series package to plot data would be better.

Here's the sample code and I use the data Canada under library vars to ensure it is replicable:

```
library(timeSeries)
library(timeDate)
library(xts)  
library(xtsExtra)
library(vars)
data(Canada)  
plot.xts(Canada,screens=1)
```

So I am really eager to ask some plausible ways to add additional `y-axis` on the `xts-based` time series plot. Hope my words were not so rookie enough...

Comment: It's hard to add an additional axis - by design. I recommend faceting. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html for some examples of what I mean.

Comment: I just checked with your link on ggplot(). But I was required to do an additional y-axis on the same plot since actually I only have two time series lines... I guess the concern is that time series packages mask the normal functions in R or I know it might be hard to put the additional y-axis in a nice format or well matched with the original one if two data lines varies huge in means & variances.